# Why does voltage change in series circuit but not in parallel circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

Voltage divides after every resistor in series but not when placed in parallel. Please explain this with using very less or no mathematical equations. 
I have tried searching for an answer online but every one just says that it changes or tells about how much it changes. I want to know why it changes in series and why it doesnot change in parallel. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, The phenomenon you are asking about has a name, Kirchoff's Voltage Law (known to electrical engineers as "KVL")  KVL does not, in and of itself, answer your question, but if you google for it, perhaps you will find some articles with useful information.

Answer (score 13):

Assume you have four waterfalls, and they connect one river to another.  The waterfalls drop by five feet.  If you put the waterfalls end to end, then the second river must be 20 feet below the first river.  If, however, the waterfalls get put side by side, and still connect the two rivers, the second river is just five feet below the first river.

Now, this is exactly the same arrangement using gravitational potential that you get with resistors.  The first arrangement is series, and the second one is parallel.

Comment: I was going to give an answer using intuition about water pipes with half-open valves, but this answer is just as good if not better.

Answer (score 1):

since voltage increases with resistance if we connect resistors in series the resistance too will increase with increase in voltage which is usually undesired so the votmeter is arranged in such a way that it gives least resistance and maximum current and that's why voltage gets divided In series. 
For parallel resistors since change of voltage of one resistor will not effect the voltage of other resistor and hence there is no alteration in the current due to voltage.hence voltage is taken constant in parallel circuit